# Can't Install gem install mysql2 Ruby WINx64

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, installation, extconf.rb

I've been searching for this error, reinstaled everything, and tried everthing. All I found here are old posts, and old versions. 
Yes, I've downloaded MySQL C Connector and move the lib to that ruby dir. Still nothing.

Im running a PC WINx64 
Ruby version 2.0.0-p195
Lastest Version of DevKit

```
**gem install mysql2**
**Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
        --with-libmysqllib
        --without-libmysqllib


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out**

B:\ROR\hcv>
```

Windows is giving me problems all time. But this is all I have at Work. Thank You guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've downloaded the connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=412857

and typed in the command prompt

**gem install mysql --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-include=C:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.0-winx64\include --with-mysql-lib=C:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.0-winx64\lib**

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the mysql gem using following command

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\lib\opt" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\include"'
```

*note: Change the mysql installation directory as per your installation*